# Implementing Log4J in desktop application

Tags: java

I am implementing Log4J 2 in my existing application and stuck with minor doubts. Any help will be appreicated :-

It's a dsktop application and will be packaged in exe format. I want to write my logs to the directory whereever the exe is executed and installed.

I tried putting in the following line in the xml file but doesn't seems to be working. Can somebody explain me what does root means ? and how my problem can be solved.

```
<param name="File" value=" ${root}Application/logs/ENID.log"/>
```

Comment: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=31

Comment: You are implementing a Log4j appender or you're just rewriting your whole code? And how should we know how your changes affect XML parsing?

Answer (score 0):

"value" attribute holds the log file path.this is set in class path.

```
system.setProperty("root","Log File Path");
```

Your code:

```
<param name="File" value=" ${root}Application/logs/ENID.log"/>
```

change it to:

```
<param name="File" value=" ${root}"/>
```

Eg:

```
system.setProperty("root" ,"c:/logs/mylog.log")
```

Comment: Is there any way I can write the logs in the eclipse workspace directory without hardcoding that ???? I tried using the below command but not working for me..  <param name="File" value=" ./logs/mylog.log"/>

Comment: directly put your workspace path 
<param name="File" value="workspace/foldername/ENID.log"/>